# Entering UK on US passport with different name to the BRP

Tags: uk-visa

My wife and I visited the USA. I am a Uk national resident in the Uk. My wife is a US national living with me in the UK on a BRP. My wife lost her US passport and had to apply for a new one. The only ID she had was her US driving license which has a different surname to her lost passport. Her passport will now have a different name to the BRP. Will she be able to come into the UK?

Comment: What paperwork does she have relating the two names?

Comment: She had our US marriage license and her US driving license. They would not accept the marriage license so she had to use driving license. Oh and she had hrr UK residence permit which they would not accept.

Comment: It seems strange that they would not issue a passport in her current name given the driver's license and marriage license. How does a newly married woman who wants to change her name to match her husband's get a US passport?

Comment: Ah well beats me how they work. Just worried she wont be allowed back into UK.

Comment: @Russell does the marriage license show both the name on the BRP and the name on her new passport?